# Проблема с заказчиком

Tags: заказчик

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, такая ситуация: взял заказ на фрилансе, нужно было сверстать 2 страницы. Потратил 2 дня на это, сдаю заказчику, а он говорит, что нужно было верстать не при помощи бутстрапа(Хотя в ТЗ этого не было).Теперь нужно переверстать весь макет. Может кто сталкивался с такой ситуацией? Рассудите, как поступить и что сказать заказчику.

Comment: Это же заказчик, целые анекдоты есть о них)))

Comment: Сказать, что в задании не было, поэтому переверстывание это уже отдельный заказ за отдельные деньги.

Comment: Перед тем как брать заказ указать заказчику с помощю каких технологий будет делатся работа, и уточнить какие версии браоузеров нужно поддерживать

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос к адвокатам, а не к программистам...

Answer (score 7):

Советую в этот раз сделать всё, как просит у вас заказчик. А следующий раз внимательнее составлять ТЗ.

Чем подробнее ТЗ, тем меньше сюрпризов будет возникать во время работы, в таком деле переборщить с детализацией нельзя.

Лайфхак: Кроме технических деталей, в ТЗ так же можно указывать допустимое количество правок заказчика, после того как проект сдан.